# Recording questions and answers in FHIR structures

Tags: hl7-fhir

In a verbal consultation with a patient, how can the dialog between a patient and doctor be best modeled:

```
  Q: "Do you have discomfort?"  (SCTID: 247347003)
  A: "Stomach discomfort" (SCTID: 271681002)
  A: "Chest discomfort"(SCTID: 279084009)
```

What kind of Resource models this?

I see that FHIR models Questionnaire and QuestionnaireResponse, however this doesn't seem quite right for this type of interaction because the QuestionnaireResponse must reference the Questionnaire (a published static 'document'), whereas the questions for a consultation are unique to the consultation and must be linked to both patient and doctor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're directly recording questions and answers in a coded way, it's almost certain that the conversation is being driven by a Questionnaire.  If you're post-coding general notes and approximating the questions asked and the answers given, then Observation would be the appropriate mechanism, though some questions might be better exposed using resources like FamilyMemberHistory, MedicationStatement, AllergyIntolerance, etc.  (In fact, those other resources are where you'd want the QuestionnaireResponse data to eventually be exposed too to allow better querying and analysis.)

Comment: Its free-form consultation, without a Questionnaire, but the consultation is stored in a coded way.
I see all the other structures --  Observations, etc.. many of them lose important contextual information, such, what was asked. And in particular, by its absence, what was not asked. If there's no record of what was asked, you can tell what was missed and follow up.

Comment: ... the query analysis I want to perform is what to ask. Therefore I want to know what was already asked. This information can't always be determined from Observation, etc....

Comment: Observation shouldn't lose what was asked.  That goes in Observation.code.text.  Telling what was not asked is harder.  You can tell what was not *recorded* and linked to the Encounter.  How studious clinicians are about recording questions asked that don't have "interesting" answers varies.  However, that problem is the same regardless of how the information gets recorded.

Comment: If it's coded, use Observation.code.coding.  The actual text the user *saw* goes in Observation.code.text

Comment: That would be the answer part, no? Not the question.

Comment: Observation.code (text and/or coding) is the question, Observation.value is the answer.